# Bootcamp Entrance Exam Question - CheckerLogger Closure Problem in Javascript

Tags: javascript, closures, javascript-objects

This is an exam question from a live bootcamp. I hit a wall and cannot figure out why the code is failing to execute properly. What am I doing wrong?

This is the provided prompt:

> Create a function `checkerLogger` that takes one argument (a function that returns a boolean value) The returned function should have the following behavior:
> If the function is invoked with an argument, the checker callback function is invoked and its boolean result is returned.
> If the function is invoked without any arguments, instead return a count of the number of times the callback function has been invoked and evaluated true or false.

Example: What you're supposed to get

```
const isOdd = num => num % 2 === 1;

const oddCounter = checkerLogger(isOdd);

console.log(oddCounter()); //-> { true: 0, false: 0 }

console.log(oddCounter(3)); //-> true

console.log(oddCounter(2)); //-> false

console.log(oddCounter()); //-> { true: 1, false: 1 }
```

My Code:

```js
function checkerLogger (cb) {
  const cache = {};
  return function (arg){
    let result = cb(arg)
    if (arg){
      return result;
    }

    if (cache.hasOwnProperty(result)){
      cache[result] += 1;
    } else {
      cache[result] = 0
    }

    return cache;
  }
}

const isOdd = num => num % 2 === 1;

const oddCounter = checkerLogger(isOdd);

console.log(oddCounter()); //-> { true: 0, false: 0 }

console.log(oddCounter(3)); //-> true

console.log(oddCounter(2)); //-> false

console.log(oddCounter()); //-> { true: 1, false: 1 }
```

My outputs:

```
{ false: 0 } 

true 

false 

{ false: 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the `cache` object as:

```
const cache = { true: 0, false: 0 }
```

This will help you avoid the check for whether the `true` or `false` property exists in the `cache` object or not.

Inside the returned function, first check if it has been called with no argument or not. If no argument is provided, simply return the `cache` object.

```
if (arg == undefined) {
   return cache;
}
```

If the argument has been provided, call the callback function and then update the `cache` object.

```
let result = cb(arg);
cache[result] += 1;
```

Finally, return the `result`.

#### Demo

```js
function checkerLogger(cb) {

  const cache = { true: 0, false: 0 };

  return function(arg) {
    if (arg == undefined) {
      return cache;
    }
    
    let result = cb(arg);
    cache[result] += 1;  
    
    return result;
  }
}

const isOdd = (num) => num % 2 === 1;
const oddCounter = checkerLogger(isOdd);

console.log(oddCounter());
console.log(oddCounter(2));
console.log(oddCounter(2));
console.log(oddCounter(3));
console.log(oddCounter());
```

#### Edit

As per your comment, you don't want to initialize the `cache` constant with an object containing `true` and `false` properties.

Following demo shows how you can do that and still get the same output.

```js
function checkerLogger(cb) {

  const cache = {};

  return function(arg) {
    if (arg == undefined) {
      return { true: cache['true'] ?? 0, false: cache['false'] ?? 0 };
    }
    
    let result = cb(arg);
 
    if (cache[result] != undefined) {
      cache[result] += 1;
    } else {
      cache[result] = 1;
    }
    
    return result;
  }
}

const isOdd = (num) => num % 2 === 1;
const oddCounter = checkerLogger(isOdd);

console.log(oddCounter());
console.log(oddCounter(2));
console.log(oddCounter(2));
console.log(oddCounter(3));
console.log(oddCounter());
```

Comment: Wow thank you, thats nearly what I'm looking for. by changing the last "return cache" to a "return result" - I do get the result I need. 

But is there a way to get the answer without declaring true and false in the object. I'd like to get the function to declare the keys dynamically.